# How do I localize the Status page in ASP.net Razor Program.cs file using .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm building a web site using asp.net razor (.NET 6).

In my program.cs file, I'm adding my localization like below. Note I am using localization friendly urls. So urls will be domain.com/{culture}/page.

This works perfectly.

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    // Set up localization friendly urls here.
    options.Conventions.Add(new CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention());
});
 
// Add the folder where localization resources will be stored.
builder.Services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddViewLocalization();
builder.Services.AddMvc().AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
 
// ADD THE SUPPORTED AND DEFAULT CULTURE!
builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new[]
        {
             new CultureInfo("en-CA"),
             new CultureInfo("fr-CA"),
         };
 
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-CA");
    options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
    options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider { Options = options });
});
```

Then at the bottom of the program.cs file, I'm adding support for the status code pages.

```
app.UseStatusCodePages();
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/en-ca/Status{0}");
```

This is where I'm having the issue. How do I get the status page to localize? If the culture is missing of course, it does not find the page.

I have tried this

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/" + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.ToLowerInvariant() + "/Status{0}");
```

But that still just displays in english for some reason.

Is there a way to dynamically set the culture here or is there another way I should be doing this?